# Fooling a commercial security door using printed scan of a fingerprint

Tags: security, airport-security

According to wikipedia,the popular program called MythBusters were able to fool a security door with a printed scan of a fingerprint

> ^ "Crimes and Myth-Demeanors 1". Mythbusters. episode 16. season 4.
>   Yes. July 12, 2006. The Discovery Channel.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biometrics#cite_note-52

How true is this and how have things changed to mitigate the jaw dropping error in the biometric system?.

Comment: or they didn't reset the lock properly the lock check the youtube [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkvwhInv828)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, a few links:

Over on Security Stack Exchange we have [discussed this exact case](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/11681/485).

Noted security commentator Bruce Schneier has [some interesting discussion](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/04/security_risks_2.html) - and in fact it is a recurring theme.

> Most fingerprint readers have independently measured EER of 5%; the
>   best ones allegedly get down to about 0.2%. That means that when the
>   system is set to a sensitivity such that it only randomly locks you
>   out one time in 200 (say, 3 times a year), a crook has a 1 in 200
>   chance of stealing your car just be swiping his finger on the reader
>   and seeing if it works by luck.

The Chaos Computer Club in Germany has an [excellent piece on how they did this](http://www.ccc.de/updates/2008/schaubles-finger) to Dr Wolfgam Schauble, the Home Secretary. (You might want to google translate that link if you can't speak German) - basically they got his fingerprint from a glass, made it more visible using cyanoacrylate (like you will have seen on NCIS or CIS), took a photograph using a digital camera and printed it onto wood glue which could then be attached to their own fingertips.

The problem is that in order for a biometric system to work it needs to reject the wrong finger (or retina or whatever) but allow the right one in a world where nothing is perfect.

Fingers might be presented at a different angle, or pressed a little too hard etc., so a little leeway is required in order to make sure valid users are allowed in. In addition, only a number of points are selected, not the entire fingerprint, which further reduces the accuracy required.

[image]

image from http://www.rtcmagazine.com/articles/view/100725

So the trade-off is between false accepts and false rejects - which leads to the possibility of using faked fingerprints, such as a printout, or the amusing [gummy bear fingerprints](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2002/05/16/gummi_bears_defeat_fingerprint_sensors/) used by Matsumoto.

> Matsumoto took a photo-sensitive printed-circuit board (which can be
>   found in many electronic hobby shops) and used the fingerprint
>   transparency to etch the fingerprint into the copper. From this he
>   made a gelatine finger using the print on the PCB, using the same
>   process as before. Again this fooled fingerprint detectors about 80
>   per cent of the time.

It is not a jaw-dropping error, it is actually well within design parameters. Biometrics can never be 100% accurate, and in fact if it was it would be useless as a security tool - as soon as your biometrics changed you would be locked out. Have a read of **[this question on Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6349/485)** for more information on why biometrics are used **as well as** username and password, not **instead of**.

Comment: *"why biometrics are used as well as username and password, not instead of."* Yup. Some thing you are and (something you know and/or something you have). Or for convenience; and for maximum security.

Comment: gosh, what does means yes or no?

Comment: @Rafael.IT - it means yes, this is real, it has been tested in various different forms by a range of security professionals and amateurs and it works. The answer above just explains why it works and why it isn't really an error, more a product of functional requirements.